# Talend and Apache Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, etl, talend, data-integration

I am confused as to where Talend and Apache spark fit in the big data ecosystem as both Apache Spark and Talend can be used for ETL.

Could someone please explain this with an example?

Comment: Talend Big Data Studio : https://youtu.be/tPeFzANfELk

Comment: https://www.talend.com/solutions/information-technology/talend-spark/

Answer (score 1):

Talend is kind of tool based big data approach and supports all big data applications with in built components. Where as spark is code base approach and you need to write the code for use case.

Answer (score 0):

In fact Talend Big Data studio generates Apache Spark code for the designed ETL jobs. So in essence they are the same.

Comment: So in essence they are the same ... cannot be true. One codes the spark with scala, java, pyspark themselves. the other generates code, they may equate functionally to the same thing, bu they are not the same thing. Hope this helps

Comment: The question was asked with ETL in mind, so in that context they are essentially the same, instead of writing your own Spark code you generate it. Apache Spark as a whole is another beast.

The context is important here, for example other ETL vendors require a middle-ware to be able to run on Spark clusters, so they are not pure Spark.

Comment: so you agree with me

Answer (score 0):

Talend studio provides inbuilt components for spark is the main engine behind this. Due to the inbuilt components it decreases the coding time. But if you will code directly using spark with Scala java or python it needs time to build the common components. Talend makes life easier and it’s easy to adopt for the traditional etl developers. Example if someone comes from abi initio they can correlate by seeing the graph or lineage provided by Talend. But in order to extend the business component people need to write code I. Java with spark in the Talend studio. One more thing Talend takes care of packaging the jar and deploying it from windows to server and run and displays the result in its console.