# What is exactly the need of spark when using talend?

Tags: apache-spark, etl, talend

I am new to both spark and talend.

But I read everywhere that both of these are ETL tools. I read another stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371279/talend-and-apache-spark). From the other answer what I understood is talend do use spark for large data processing. But can talend do all the ETL work efficiently that spark is doing without using spark under the hood? Or is it essentially a wrapper over spark where all the data is send to talend is actually put inside the spark inside talend for processing?

I am quite confused with this. Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Informatica BDM which has its own Blaze framework for processing on Hadoop (native), Talend relies on other frameworks such as Map Reduce (Hadoop using possibly tez underneath) or Spark engine. So you could avoid Spark, but there is less point in doing so. The key point is that we could expect I think some productivity using Talend as it is graphical based, which is handy when there are many fields and you do not need possibly the most skilled staff.

For NOSQL, like HBase, they provide specific connectors or could use the Phoenix route. Talend also has connectors for KAFKA.

Comment: So if I say that talend on its on is a flow management system like nifi would I be wrong?

Comment: Yes, I worked with NIFI recently and I loved it. But it is not an ETL tool, it is a light weight mover of data and it has many things, but do not try to use it for Type 2 dimension processing, for example.

Comment: But even in Talend the huge processing is done with spark or storm or some framework right? won't building some connector for Nifi (not sure if some solution exists)  to spark or some other processing tool would make them same?

Comment: No, NIFI is just to transport from source x to target y and lightly transform the data for further processing. But it was an NSA project and it can still do a lot but not real ETL

Comment: Just one more thing though...is Talend as good as Nifi in fetching data in realtime from various data sources like MySQL, REST APIs etc. Or is talend more of a batch processing tool?

Comment: talend can access kafka. it all becomes a bit blurred in this domain. bothered possible. good point.

Answer (score 1):

Spark is just one of the frameworks supported by Talend. When you create a new job, you can pick Spark from the dropdown list. You can get more details [in the docs](https://help.talend.com/r/bYQYL576UebCj3V76mUoeA/svekiZRvdXnsuccbPLg6Ow).

[image]

Comment: So can talend as an ETL tool perform these huge data processing without any frameworks like spark or storm? Does it have any inbuilt framework or library or tool to process large data?

Comment: I don't think so, the only way to use Talend for the Big Data that I know is Hadoop. Let me quote the docs:

"However, to reap the benefits of Hadoop, data analysts need a way to load data into Hadoop and subsequently extract it from this open source system. This is where Talend studio comes in. Built on top of Talend's data integration solutions, Talend studio enable users to handle big data easily by leveraging Hadoop and its databases or technologies such as HBase, HCatalog, HDFS, Hive, Oozie and Pig."

https://help.talend.com/r/C8mznD9TYsuB~SWG77PPDQ/cS88RTvurLwC5HyV_LPsnA

Comment: But I can be wrong, I'm not a huge Talend fan. Maybe someone could provide you more helpful advice.